# Peak Inverse Voltage of full wave rectifier in case of different diodes

Tags: diodes, bridge-rectifier

Does the peak inverse voltage remain the same for all the diodes in a full wave rectifier, when we are using both germanium and silicon diodes in the rectifier circuit?

Comment: Yes. It does because the diodes, regardless of type, are blocking the AC voltage for peak inverse voltage

Comment: Then what will be the value of piv for 0.3 and 0.7V in case of bridge rectifier ?
'Rl(load output) + 0.3' or 'Rl(load output) + 0.7' 
or something else ?

Comment: No. PIV is the voltage the diode needs to BLOCK. It has nothing to do with the forward voltage across the diode when it conducts.